# Display NO Data when Ajax success is empty or null

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a WebMethod, which is populating a JQuery DataTable with some initial values. I have a drop down list, which calls the WebMethod and try to populate it with different values. My problem, is if the JSON data is null (or '') then i get  JSON.parse: unexpected end of data.

Now, I can check the length of the object using `if(msg.d.length !- '' { build the table} )` However, if the length is null (''), then i never go into the build table, and therefore cant present that there is no data / no records.

How can I ensure that if the JSON string/object is null ('') that DataTables still presents No Records found etc...?

```
 $('#ddBICS').change(function (e) {

              var val = $('#dd option:selected').text();

              msgDateDetail(val);

          });


function msgDateDetail(value) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Default.aspx/MsgDateDetail",
             cache: false,
             data: JSON.stringify({ searchValue: value }),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",

             success: function (msg) {
                 var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                 var asInitVals = new Array();

                 otblMsgDateDetail = $("#tblMsgDateDetail").dataTable({
                     "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                     "oTableTools": {
                         "aButtons": [
                         "copy",
                         "print",
                         {
                             "sExtends": "collection",
                             "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                             "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                         }
                         ]
                     },

                     "aaData": data
                 })
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: With the little code you have posted you could at least post some valid one...

Comment: @CSharpNewBee please add the entire msgDateDetail method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

msg could be null or undefined, just checking for the variable will tell you that.  Also since you're using JQuery you could check if d is an array with the isArray JQuery method.

```
if(msg && msg.d && $.isArray(msg.d) && msg.d.length > 0) { 
   // build the table 
}else{
   // data is empty
}
```

Within your above method you would do the following.

```
function msgDateDetail(value) {
  $('#tblMsgDate
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Default.aspx/MsgDateDetail",
     cache: false,
     data: JSON.stringify({ searchValue: value }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",

     success: function (msg) {
         var asInitVals = new Array();

         var data = (msg && msg.d && $.isArray(msg.d))? msg.d : new Array();

          otblMsgDateDetail = $("#tblMsgDateDetail").dataTable({
             "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
             "oTableTools": {
                 "aButtons": [
                 "copy",
                 "print",
                 {
                     "sExtends": "collection",
                     "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                     "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                 }
                 ]
             },

             "aaData": data
          })                  
     }
  });
}
```

The documentation for the jquery method is located on jquery.com http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/

For this to work make sure that your Default.aspx/MsgDateDetail returns application/json for the content type.  To do this in the aspx file you do the following:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
```

You must do this before you do any Response.Write

Comment: Moe, this is the logic I have, however, this still doesn't present the ned user with a datatbale that reads no records. It presents the same info prior the request

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Please post your code, you're most likely not clearing out your data table before the update but I would need to see that code to make a distinction

Comment: DataTable now displays the No records all the time

Comment: @CSharpNewBee please check out updated code, the data that's coming back must be in a string you have to ensure that it's in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You should the length like this

```
if(msg.d.length !=0) {  // Try this
  //-- build the table
 }
```

Comment: Well spotted, that was a typo - however, i need to check for a emmpty string, as I pass back a JSON string, and then parse it.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee why not set dataType of your ajax request as json ??? If json returned by server is not valid, error callback will be fired

Comment: Don't have control to change that i'm afraid. I'm in charge of making it work from a UI stand-point

Comment: Javascript should be your side. without this you fight this one.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I haven't downvoted.  But I can predict, they wanted you to give a clear picture of your problem.

Comment: wasnt aimed at you specifically.

Comment: `success: function (msg) { if(msg.length != 0) { alert('No Data') break;}` this must have worked.